# Unable to load an existing spring application context

Tags: java, spring, jsp, applicationcontext

I have a requirement where I've to load some properties from DB to a bean in Spring Application Context, by making a call from a JSP file. 
I have a Web project which has my JSP file, and I have an EJB project, which has my Spring application context. I'm trying to reload the properties by making a call to a class/servlet in my Web project, which will call the service layer. Both these projects are packaged into and EAR and deployed on to the server.
I know this method is not the best but this utility is a temporary one, need to use it as long as we build an Admin module.

I've tried to load the existing context a couple of ways, but I'm getting null value in it.
1) In JSP file:

```
ApplicationContext ctx=WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
```

2) In a class which extends ApplicationContextAware interface:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextAwareProvider implements ApplicationContextAware  {
    static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context=context;
    }
}
```

Inside JSP:

```
MyBean myBean = ApplicationContextProvider().getContext().getBean("myBean",MyBean.class);
```

Getting NullPointerException in both the cases as my ApplicationContext would always be null. Am I doing something wrong ?

Is it because the ApplicationContext is not available for the WebProject? Please let me know your thoughts.. stuck on this tiny thing for a couple of days.

Comment: why are you even calling java code from inside a jsp?

Comment: Like I mentioned, this is just a temporary workaround. We'll be building an admin module later and include this in it, don't have time to design this temporary solution.